# Cannot destructure property

Tags: javascript, jquery

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `results` of 'undefined' or
>   'null'.
>       at displayCartTotal

```
 const displayCartTotal = ({results}) => {

  };

  const fetchBill = () => {
    const apiHost = 'https://randomapi.com/api';
    const apiKey = '006b08a801d82d0c9824dcfdfdfa3b3c';
    const apiEndpoint = `${apiHost}/${apiKey}`;

    fetch(apiEndpoint) 
    .then( response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(results => {
        console.log(results.results)
        displayCartTotal();
     })
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

Comment: Can you update the question? Its not much clear whats your exact problem is, the code you post is breaking

Comment: Try `console.log(results)` instead of `console.log(results.results)`

Comment: You didn't pass any param to displayCartTotal() function and probably you are destructing results in that function that's why you have such error.

Comment: in second resolve call displayCartTotal(results) instead of  displayCartTotal() and would be nice if you check before calling displayCartTotal(results), if results contain results property for not having errors in future

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because you aren't passing `results` into `displayCartTotal` like `displayCartTotal(results)`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `displayCartTotal()` with no parameter, but it expects an object. See commented line below:

```js
const displayCartTotal = ({results}) => {

  };

  const fetchBill = () => {
    const apiHost = 'https://randomapi.com/api';
    const apiKey = '006b08a801d82d0c9824dcfdfdfa3b3c';
    const apiEndpoint = `${apiHost}/${apiKey}`;

    fetch(apiEndpoint) 
    .then( response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(results => {
        console.log(results.results)
        displayCartTotal(); //<--- this is the offending line
     })
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

You should pass results as a parameter like this: `displayCartTotal(results)`.

Hope that solves it for you :)